# Make a dxtextbox (devextreme) readonly when the dxtextbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, devextreme

This is the code I used, but it does not work also I should also insert in a button some code to clean the textbox when I press it.

```js
$("#textbox").dxTextBox({
   options: {
      onClick: function() {
       $('#textbox').prop("readonly", true);
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to add a button for remove value inside textbox right?

Comment: @errorau yes you can do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `showClearButton` properies

```
     <div class="dx-field">
           <div class="dx-field-label">With clear button</div>
           <div class="dx-field-value">
           <div id="clear-button"></div>
      </div>
```

you can call `showClearButton` prop

```
  $("#clear-button").dxTextBox({
        value: "John Smith",
        showClearButton: true
    });
```

also you can see all example about dx-textbox

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TextBox/Overview/jQuery/Light/